# No HTTP response code found error

Tags: joomla-3.x

`Error: No HTTP response code found.`

I am migrating a component from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3. After migrating my component when I tried to install using install from directory I got this error.

Any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 2):

**Installing from directory and installing from a packed extension follow two different installation paths.** (two similar but separate pieces of code handle the installation process).

To put it with other words, the **installation from directory** works for very basic components, which do not use update sites, sql updates, etc but **can be sometimes rather buggy.**

So build your component as a installable component and try it on a clean system.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the attribute location in #__update_sites. Try each of them in your browser. Correct or remove the one giving the error.